# Shadows and planar sections of polyhedra – 2

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-geometry

This post continues [Shadows and planar sections of polyhedra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402665/shadows-and-planar-sections-of-polyhedra) and [On planar sections of 3D convex bodies](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401298/on-planar-sections-of-3d-convex-bodies)

[Shadows and planar sections of polyhedra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402665/shadows-and-planar-sections-of-polyhedra) gives an example demonstrating that *shadows* (orthogonal projection of a convex 3D body onto a 2D plane) and planar sections of convex bodies are independent concepts - specifically, the max area shadow of a 3d convex body need not be any planar section at all of the body.

Here, we restate questions asked in [On planar sections of 3D convex bodies](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401298/on-planar-sections-of-3d-convex-bodies) with "shadow" replacing "planar section" as follows:

Consider the set of shadows of any given convex 3D body.

**Basic Question:** What is the lower bound for the ratio
$$\frac{\text{area of shadow of greatest perimeter}}
{\text{area of shadow of greatest area}}\ ?$$

And which convex solid gives it?

**Generalization:** Consider the set of quantities: {area, perimeter, diameter, width,...}. Take each pair (x,y) of such quantities. What are bounds on the corresponding ratios for those pairs?

**Further questions:** From among convex bodies for which two quantities x and y from the above set are maximized by the same shadow, will a third quantity z be maximized by another shadow? If so how to quantify this difference? And which convex solid gives it?

And how to characterize polyhedra for which a given type of special shadow *is* a planar section?